# Дан отрезок [A,B]. Вывести на экран все нечетные числа из этого отрезка, не делящиеся на 3. Найти сумму таких чисел

Tags: c++

Дан отрезок [A,B]. Вывести на экран все нечетные числа из этого отрезка, не делящиеся на 3. Найти сумму таких чисел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не получается ввечти сумму чисел , но вывод чисел есть

Comment: если красиво отформатрировать (и приложить код текстом, а не картинкой), то станет очевидно, что Вы пытаетесь вывести числа от 0 до b (включительно), которые не кратны 2 и 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int n = a; n <= b; ++n) {
    if (n%3 != 0 && n%2 != 0)
    {
        f += n;
        cout << "Число " << n << "\n";
    }
}
cout << "Сумма равна " << f << "\n";
```